# Pentaho CE report executes KTR tranformate twice

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-report-designer

I'm using **Pentaho CE** for general reporting.

We are running reports using the build In Report Viewer.

We've noticed that each report created using **Report Designer** and using **KTR** as data source executes transformate twice ... (as seen in logs)

For large, complicated KTRs with SQL queries this is an overkill.
Does anyone know what is the purpose of this ? How can this be changed ? or just give me some light on the subject ?

Thanks, help much appreciated.

Comment: It should not be the case, share your report file, how you implemented this?

Comment: This is just a simple ktr file with 4 blocks: Table input (postgresql) + sort + group + dummy output. But we have at least 16 reports and all of them behave the same. Also those two times are not one after another ... the processing starts .... then when I can see first progress, ktr is executed second time ....

Comment: share your sample report with .prpt and .ktr file and let me check.

Comment: Sorry but meantime I've changed project and forgot about this issue. Thanks for your interest.